# Assigning input markers to function output in python

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry for the seemingly elementary question. What I'm trying to implement is summarized in the following steps:

1. Generate input variables: x, y.
2. Let z = F(x,y).
3. Plot z's for particular combinations of x and y.

For example:

```
zlist = []
for _ in range(100):
    x = np.random.random()*1.
    y = np.random.random()*.5
    if x < .5:
        z = y / 2
    else:
        z = y * 2
    zlist.append(z)
```

Now if I want to plot z for all the x between (0, 0.3), I presumably would need some marker on each element in zlist indicating its inputs variables. How would I attach such marker and then access it from the list when plotting?

Comment: a nitpick of convention -- if you're looping through an iterable but you don't ever need its iteration (as in your `for i in range(100)`, use an underscore (e.g. `for _ in range(100)`). There's nothing special about the underscore, but it's immediately clear to the reader that it's a throwaway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually know anything about Numpy, so someone please comment and tell me if I'm making a fool out of myself. It seems like vanilla python behavior, though.

Rather than appending z, let's append (z,x) instead. Now zlist is a list of tuples, and you can loop through and plot by checking zlist[i][1].

```
zlist = []
for _ in range(100):
    x = np.random.random()*1.
    y = np.random.random()*.5
    if x < .5:
        z = y / 2
    else:
        z = y * 2
    zlist.append((z,x))

for value in zlist:
    if value[1] > 0 and value[1] < 0.3:
        # Plot value[0]
# Or if you prefer list comprehensions:
# [value[0] for value in zlist if value[1] >0 and value[1] < 0.3]
# that will return a list with only the z values in zlist.
```

Answer (score 1):

With numpy it's almost always much more efficient to perform operations on vectors and
arrays rather than on built-in Python sequence types such as lists. Here's one
way you can quickly find *F(x, y)* for every combination of two sets of random x
and y values without looping in Python. The result is going to be an nx-by-ny
array `Z`, where `Z[i, j] = F(x[i], y[j])`.

First of all, you can generate all of your x, y inputs as vectors:

```
nx = 100
ny = 200
x = np.random.random(size=nx) * 1.
y = np.random.random(size=ny) * 5.
```

For the result to be an nx-by-ny array, you could take these two vectors and
multiply them by ones to get two 2D nx-by-ny arrays containing the x and y
values in the rows and columns respectively. You can do this by taking advantage of numpy's
[broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
x_arr = x[:,np.newaxis] * np.ones((nx,ny))
y_arr = y[np.newaxis,:] * np.ones((nx,ny))
```

The function you will apply to each x,y pair depends on the x value.
Fortunately, you can use `np.where(<condition>, <do_this>, <do_that>)` to apply
different operations to the values in your input depending on some condition:

```
Z = np.where(x_arr < 0.5, y_arr / 2., y_arr * 2.)
```

We can check that all the results are correct:

```
for i in xrange(nx):
    for j in xrange(ny):
        if x[i] < 0.5:
            assert Z[i, j] == y[j] / 2.
        else:
            assert Z[i, j] == y[j] * 2
```

There's actually an even cleaner way to compute `Z` without expanding `x` and `y` into 2D arrays. Using the same broadcasting trick we used to get
`x_arr` and `y_arr`, you can pass `x` and `y` directly to `np.where()`:

```
x2 = x[:,np.newaxis]
y2 = y[np.newaxis,:]

Z2 = np.where(x2 < 0.5, y2 / 2., y2 * 2.)

assert np.all(Z == Z2)
```